# Best way to read huge files from S3 using Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Requirement is to read files each <4GB and push the data to some other location. I wrote my own implementation of getResources() by extending PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver class, so as to populate the resource array as below:

```
@Override
public Resource[] getResources(String locationPattern) throws IOException {
    Set<Resource> resources = new HashSet<Resource>();
    AmazonS3 s3Client = streamingClient.getS3Client();
    for (S3ObjectSummary summary : S3Objects.withPrefix(s3Client, this.awsConfiguration.getS3Bucket(),
            this.awsConfiguration.getS3BucketKey())) {
        S3Object s3object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(this.awsConfiguration.getS3Bucket(), summary.getKey()));
        resources.add(new S3Resource(summary.getKey(), s3object.getObjectContent()));
    }
    return resources.toArray(new Resource[resources.size()]);
}
```

As you can see, i read all resources and build a Resource array and return it. I think thats bad idea, rather than I prefer to pass the stream to somethread and continue to extract data and not to wait until all resources are populated in Resource array.

Another draw back what i see is, holding the S3ObjectStream, which will block my request poolsize from S3.

Is there any other way which I can use to build a reader ??

Below is the data format, A1 has 1k + files, A2 has 1k+ files, each of size < 4GB.

`` <bucket>
  `--- A1/
        `--- file1.txt
        `---- file2.txt
   `---A2/
       `----- file3.txt
........... ``

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

There is already a way of getting a list of resources in an S3 bucket.  Spring Cloud AWS provides an S3Resource implementation that handles this so you don't need to read the entire resource to get a list of resources.  I use it in my S3JDBC example found here: https://github.com/mminella/s3jdbc